# Jboss not getting installed

Tags: linux, jboss, centos

I  am trying to install Jboss on linux machine (centos). I am just copying the jboss folder. and running run.sh file. but it does not start and displays error saying that

```
    Could not create deployment: file:/opt/apps/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml
         org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable: (java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:251)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:236)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:451)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:171)
        ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl.<init>()V from class org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig
        at org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig.<init>(XMLLoginConfig.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:1233)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:286)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:344)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:157)
        ... 38 more
     Failed to boot JBoss:
   org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: - nested throwable:     (java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:196)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:226)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at    org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.install(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.create(SARDeployer.java:251)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at  org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:236)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:451)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.install(ServiceConfigurator.java:171)
        ... 36 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfigImpl.<init>()V from class org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig
        at org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig.<init>(XMLLoginConfig.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:1233)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.instantiate(MBeanServerImpl.java:286)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.createMBean(MBeanServerImpl.java:344)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:157)
```

What could be the possible error.

Comment: Difficult to knoww which service failed, is there any other exception down the line?

Comment: edited the question. complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Found it finally myself. 
In /etc/hosts file entry for 127.0.0.1 was not the appropriate.

Comment: Pretty sure the problem has nothing to do with hosts file (that problem could be this: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExceptionCreatingIdentity )

Instead the problem may be related on the order of jar loading inside server\default\lib for example. In my case I had that problem because picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar was being loaded before jbosssx.jar and that causes that exact exception. jboss 4.2.3